# How to save a file on Dropbox using dropbox-saver API

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, dropbox-api

I share with you a part of my code which is for doing an encryption to files. This code works fine when I tried to save an encrypted file on local hard drive but when I tried to save an encrypted file on the Cloud using JavaScript Saver API, I just got the data in the form of data URI. Any of you have an idea for how this issue could be tackled?

// JavaScript Code:

```
// The HTML5 FileReader object will allow us to read the 
    // contents of the  selected file.

    var reader = new FileReader();

    if(body.hasClass('encrypt')){

        // Encrypt the file!

        reader.onload = function(e){

            // Use the CryptoJS library and the AES cypher to encrypt the 
            // contents of the file, held in e.target.result, with the password

            var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(e.target.result, password);

            // The download attribute will cause the contents of the href
            // attribute to be downloaded when clicked. The download attribute
            // also holds the name of the file that is offered for download.


            a.attr('href', 'data:application/octet-stream,' + encrypted);
            a.attr('download', file.name + '.encrypted');



            step(4);
        };

        // This will encode the contents of the file into a data-uri.
        // It will trigger the onload handler above, with the result

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
```

// HTML Code

```
            <div class="content">
                <h1>Your file is ready!</h1>
                <a class="button download green">Download on Computer</a>
                <a class="button download dropbox-saver green">Cloud</a>

            </div>

        </div>
```

Thanks in advance for all your assistant and efforts.

Comment: The Dropbox Saver doesn't support data URIs, unfortunately, but we'll consider it a feature request.

Comment: @Greg -- Please do. Otherwise, Dropbox is not useful with an offline web-app that works with local files without using a relay server.